# reading from file: file doesn't exist

Tags: objective-c

I have an App both in C# and Objective-C, that has to read from text file. Since the text file is created after the App, the user has the option to save it anywhere. In C# it was not difficult to find the file, only using file name with out the full path. In Objective-C this seems to be difficult. I can't ask the users to save it at specific Path, it is against Apple's App regulation. Any Idea how to search for the particular file with only filename? During my trial I used NSFileManager to detect the file, and the App can read the file if it is saved in Applications(Mac),But if i save the file in Documents or anywhere else , gives me Error:'file doesn't exist'.

Comment: It would help if you condensed it down to the smallest amount of code illustrating your issue and shared your code.  It's hard for others to guess what you may be doing wrong :)

Comment: Have you updated your "Capabilities" for your app to allow for "File Access -> User Selected File"? Then you can allow the user to select the file, and that will give your app permissions to open it.

Comment: @bryanmac,As i said the App can read when the text file is saved in /Applications/myfile.txt, but couldn't find the file when you change the lets say /Documents/myfile.txt.

Comment: @CraigOtis, It is very good idea, didn't even cross my mind. But it will not go with the App.I appriciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your txt file within your app folder. You can create directory.

Here is some code to create directory in Documents directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *flmngr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isDir;
if (![flmngr fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/yourDicretoryName", documentsDirectory] isDirectory:&isDir]) {

    [flmngr createDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/yourDicretoryName", documentsDirectory]
      withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                       attributes:nil
                            error:nil];
}
```

after creating specific directory. You can save your txt file. Assume you have one nsstring

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/txtFile.txt",documentsDirectory];
[yourString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

After saving your txt file you can read like this.

```
NSString *stringTxt = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

You can get the file list in directory using the code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *fileList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/yourDirectory", documentsDirectory] error:&error]];

-contentsOfDirectoryAtPath
```

returns NSArray Object. with the file names in directory.

For Cocoa Thouch Mac Application.

You can create directory using code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directory isDirectory:&isDir])
if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
    NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@", directory);
```

You can select directory using code:

```
NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setCanSelectHiddenExtension:NO];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [panel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
    [panel setTitle:@"Kaydetmek için Dosya Yolunu Seçin!"];
    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            directoryPath = [[[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0]path];
            directoryPath = [directoryPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://localhost" withString:@""];
        }
    }];
```

Writing file still same. But you can save your in documents desktop in selected or created directory etc.

Fetching file list is same.

Comment: Hi Mialkan, thank you. The users saves the text file manually, so i will try to work with out the save text file part from your code, but ask the users to save the file in that directory hoping that apple will not consider it as dictating the user to save file in specific path.

Comment: You are welcome. I made an app like this but its wating for review. My app downloads a pdf file. Before dowanload asks file name. with file name given by user I save it in Documents/Download directory. When my app is ready for sale I will let you know.  You can download this app via this link [MyApp](http://mialkan.com/kodlar/myApps/homersapien.html)